# How do I import projects from another workspace?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, ibm-rad

I started with the default workspace C:\workspace but I mange to corrupt that by removing files so now I've created a new workspace to import the files to but I don't know how to do that. Could you tell me how I import projects from another workspace? I'm using the IBM RAD which is based on eclipse.

Thank you

Comment: Open import dialog. Click on Existing project from workspace. Then in next screen Browse for project folder. Note: it will not move the whole folder.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are the steps for the original eclipse :

After switching eclipse to use the new workspace , go to `File--> Import` , and then choose `General ---> Existing Projects into Workspace` , and browse to the folder of the project that you want to import.

[image]

Comment: Only projects located inside the workspace folder are imported. Projects outside the workspace folder are not.

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse, the steps will be:

1. Select "File" tab
2. Select "Import" option in the drop down list.
3. Select "General" in the source listed.
4. Select "Archive File" if You have .zip/.rar file of the Project or "Existing Projects into Workspace" if You have Project in some other workspace.
5. Browse the Archive File or root directory location.
6. Select "Finish".

Now your project has been imported.

Answer (score 1):

I am not very familiar with RAD but if its anything like Eclipse, the projects are stored by plugins. For ex: All my java related projects are stored under

```
workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects
```

while my other projects related to another project (Seamframework related) are stored under

```
workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.tools.seam.core/projects
```

The best thing would be to search your

```
workspace/.metadata/.plugins
```

folder and see if you can identify all your projects. When you do, you can import them all into your new workspace as is.

To import the projects, once you locate them, follow the instructions posted by others here.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks. I accedentally deleted the .metadata directory (or more exactly my colleague wrongly adviced me too) and now I could create a new workspace and import the projects to there.

Comment: Ah! As best practice, I never create projects in the default workspace. I always use a separate folder for all my projects because that gives me the flexibility of cleaning up a corrupt workspace.